# How can I refresh my git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repo offline copy, and after some time somebody else might have made changes to it. How can I bring my repository up to speed with the new changes? How can I check that my repo is at its latest update?

Comment: Is there a reason why `git pull` won't work?

Comment: You should read the git book. At the very least the first 3 chapters. Here is the part you're looking for: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Fetching-and-Pulling-from-Your-Remotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git pull` will pull the latest changes.

`git fetch` will update the list of changes.
`git status` will check the status of the repo. Without the fetch first, you will not see remote changes.

Also, ***please*** read the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Fetching-and-Pulling-from-Your-Remotes).